# Can the date format of dataframe and csv file be the same?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, dataframe

The two photos that I've attached below show a dataframe table and a table that was exported out to csv file. I'm wondering if there is any command that can modify the date so that the dates shown on both files would be the same.

On the dataframe: 2017-08-01 -> but after exporting out it becomes 2017/8/1(**Instead** ->2017/08/01).
Does anyone know how it can be done, or do I can only manually edit the cell format?

[[image: Dates of the dataframe]

[image: Dates of the csv file]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

When you make the call to the `to_csv` function, you can supply it the parameter `date_format='%Y-%m-%d'`.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). One of the parameters that you can pass `to_csv` is `date_format` which allows you to control the format of your date like columns. The format is the same as for `datetime`

```
df.to_csv(file_path, date_format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 0):

The form YYYY-MM-DD should be the default output date format for `to_csv()`.

It seems like you are opening the output CSV in a program that may be applying its own style/formatting to the dates. Try opening it in a text editor to confirm.

Comment: nnikzad I normally use excel to open csv file. I tried to open it with both editor and excel, it still gives the same outcome 2017/8/1 instead of 2017/08/01